# Using a Rails project from GitHub -- server didn't start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

Hi I forked an example of a Rails app that uses Devise. It was designed as an example of how to use Devise authorization. I also cloned it to my computer.  However, when I went into the folder to start the server with  `rails s` I got an error message

```
Could not find rails (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:1210:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

I'm a little confused about the order I do things when using a Rails project from Github. For example, since I'm cloning a project, I obviously don't do `rails new app` (I assume). And then what about `bundle install`?

When creating my own rails projects I do

```
rails new app

cd app

bundle install
```

and then do `rails s` to view it on my local host.

Can you tell me what I need to change about that order to use this devise_example?

When I tried to run bundle install, it said

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:1210:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:18
```

Comment: Can you give a link to the project if it's public?

Comment: this is their project https://github.com/plataformatec/devise_example . note, i'm using ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.1 ... this project was designed as an example for rails 3.0 apparently

Comment: are you using rvm? If you are try running gem install bundler within your gemset and then running bundle install.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you don't have bundler installed.

Try running `gem install bundler` and then proceed to the app's directory and run `bundle install`

Does that help?